# Does apple watch uses its own bluetooth when i'm using corebluetooth framework in the watch kit extension, or the iPhone bluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, watchkit

It says in the the Apple Watch Guide that everything in WatchKit Extension runs on the users iPhone. So , does it mean that when I'm using CoreBluetooth functions in my WatchKit extension code, it will use the Watch Bluetooth or iPhones Bluetooth... ?

Answer (score 1):

The phone's Bluetooth, AFAIK. To paraphrase many an Apple evangelist, the Bluetooth/WiFi connection to the Watch is an implementation detail. You don't need to care about it.

Comment: Hi, can I use the core bluetooth now when the extension is on the watch and not the iphone?